# How to retrieve a array/object data values using HOF?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

Does anybody can help me how to retrieve array/object values using High Order Functions?

this is my data, the block repeats several times and I need to retrieve the resident names.

```
species: [
    {
      id: lionId,
      name: 'lions',
      popularity: 4,
      location: 'NE',
      availability: ['Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
      residents: [
        {
          name: 'Zena',
          sex: 'female',
          age: 12,
        },
     etc
```

I have tried the following code, but only can get the residents group, and I need to extract only residents names.

```
return species.map((e) => e.residents);
```

Comment: `flatMap` might work for you

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` method will return an array of arrays with resident objects inside of it. Use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to flatten the data to a single array of resident objects.

Then `map` over the resident objects and return the `name` property for each resident. This will give you an array of resident names.

```js
const species = [{
  id: '',
  name: 'lions',
  popularity: 4,
  location: 'NE',
  availability: ['Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
  residents: [{
    name: 'Zena',
    sex: 'female',
    age: 12,
  }, ],
}];

const residents = species.flatMap(specie => specie.residents);
const residentNames = residents.map(resident => resident.name);
console.log(residentNames);
```

Comment: Hi Emiel, it returns that flatmap is not a function. Any idea?

Comment: Did you write `flatmap` or `flatMap`? It should be the latter.

Comment: Both got wrong. Not a function :/

Comment: Okay. The only explanation is that you're not using it on an array. Could you append the code that you've tried to your question. Without changing the original question and code?

Comment: @KelsonBatista Where are you running this code? `flatMap` is [supported in all modern engines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#browser_compatibility).